# Angular $location.path() not redirecting on all pages

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to redirect users who are not logged in to my application to a login page.  My code is currently working on all pages except for one.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location'], function($rootScope, $location){
    if(!loggedIn){
        var returnTo = $location.path();
        $location.search("ReturnTo", returnTo);
        $location.path("account/login").replace();
    }
}
```

So far I know that on the page in question the value of $location.path is being updated, but it is not being reflected in my browser's search bar and I am seeing the original page view as opposed to the login page view.

I have seen a lot of suggestions about using $rootScope.apply() but I have not gotten any of them to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `$location.url("account/login")`;

Comment: This does not work for me.  The only benefit is that I no longer need to set the path and query string separately.  As before, a simple console.log() statement shows that the $location object is being updated, but I am still presented with the original page view instead of being taken to the login form.

Comment: Can I see the route for the login page ? Maybe the route is different. I assume it should be $location.url("/login");

Comment: `$routeProvider.when('/account/login',{
    templateUrl:'account/account-login.tpl.html',
    controller:'app.controller.account.login'
})`

Comment: Like I said, the route works on all of my other pages, it is only one page that will not redirect to the login page.